# VScode issue when trying to open a project with a big folder

Tags: visual-studio-code, explorer

I have a project with a folder that contains ~800,000 text files

[image]

FinancialDataSite_Go\SECfiles\submissions

it's the submissions folder that contains all the text files

whenever I try to open my project up in vscode I get this error

[image]

I didn't have this problem until I added all the text files to the submissions folder.

During my countless attempts to open the project folder with vscode, I had a couple successes where I can open the FinancialDataSite_Go folder in vscode but as soon as I try to open the SECfiles folder on the left bar, vscode freezes up and spit out the same error

Is vscode just unable to work with folder that contain many files?

Comment: You'll probably have better luck posting this on VScode GitHub repo: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues. Also worth trying to troubleshoot a bit. Does it open if you remove half of the text files from the folder? A quarter? Etc.

Comment: The link just eventually comes back to stackoverflow when I click on "Question". or should I be doing it as bug report?

Comment: Do you absolutely need to manually view/open those files while working in VS Code? My search foo is failing me right now, but I believe you can tell VS Code to ignore that folder, so it doesn't "process" it as part of your workspace. Then just use shell commands on the terminal to view files.

Comment: No, I don't need to view the files really, I just have them in the project folder because I want everything inside one folder. I will try to search for that ignore feature you are talking about

Comment: @GinoMempin https://youtu.be/L9s6ebZA7to?si=jhbDRH3oOdZSd3je&t=200 I think this might be what you are talking about?

Comment: No, that video is just talking about searching. The `files.exclude` setting I think is more appropriate here, as it hides the configured folders from the Explorer panel. It's useful for folders like .git and node_modules which are part of your project but you don't really need to open/view.

Comment: @GinoMempin excluding the folder worked! thank you